# Browsing for images in the editor leads to an unexpected Error

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, images, upload, kcfinder

I want to add an image in an email newsletter. However when I try to use the *Browse Server* button like: [image]

and unexpected error is thrown:

[image]

The used versions are CiviCRM 5.32.2 and Drupal 7.77

Comment: Naturally, this is a bug. I created a issue on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug that prevents users that configure multiple languages to use the *kcfinder* plugin. So check if there are more available languages are configured at https:////civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1

[image]

Restrict it to one, and try again.

At the moment a patch is available at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19245. And the PR is accepted so in later versions of CiviCRM you should not see this.